# Access a SmartCard iso14443A with Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, smartcard, mifare, omnikey

I´m trying to access the Information on a Mifare Smartcard(iso14443A) over a Omnikey 5321 CL reader.
I tried to use the [smartcard](https://github.com/tomkp/smartcard) lib, but it uses an other iso standard.
For accessing the Card I have to set a Application ID ( 3x hex), a key (32 int), keyid (hex).

Answer (score 1):

I am busy with similar process, however after searching I found this example:

- https://github.com/santigimeno/node-pcsclite

### EDIT

In fact I actually got this one working

- https://github.com/pokusew/nfc-pcsc

It returns the following:

```
ACS ACR122 0  card detected {
    atr: <Buffer 3b 8f 80 01 80 4f 0c a0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6a>,
    standard: 'TAG_ISO_14443_3',
    type: 'TAG_ISO_14443_3',
    uid: '767aec7e'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use smartcard lib, but you have to configure the reader to use the MIFARE mode instead of the T-CL variant of 14443 protocol.

If I remember corectly, the Omnikey workbench provides a graphical configuration tool for that purpose.

I strongly recommend to study [Omnikey contactless smart card readers developer guide](https://www.hidglobal.com/sites/default/files/resource_files/5321-903_b.4_omnikey_contactless_developer_guide_en.pdf), especially the section MIFARE emulation mode, for serious work.

(I have no idea, what a one byte *Application ID* means in Mifare context, and what value *3x* is supposed to represent.)